# Concatenate DWORDs

Tags: c, memory, concatenation, dword

I would like to concatenate 2 non-string types so i can use them as one.
This is the main kind of part of my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "MyProgram");
    DWORD ProcessId; GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcessId);
    HANDLE handler = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessId);
    ... ??? (type im not sure about) = 0x;          ??? ...
    ... ??? (type im not sure about) MemoryAddress; ??? ...
    int ValueOfAddress;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)(concatenated 0x+MemoryAddress), &ValueOfAddress, sizeof(ValueOfAddress), 0);
    printf("Value Of Address %? Is %d", (concatenated 0x+MemoryAddress), ValueOfAddress);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to concatenate 0x to a Memory Address that I find via ReadProcessMemory (E.G. 0x0023DA44, 0x being 0x and 0023DA44 being what the value is read from the Memory). Thanks for any help given :) sorry if this doesn't make sense im not very good at explaining. Basically I need to know how to concatenate to DWORD Data Types in order to get a memory address type variable. Any help if greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should probably try to find a training to learn C instead of playing around with "I'm not sure about"; C is hard enougth to learn not to perform guess work proramming

Comment: Yeah i get what you guys are saying but I do kinda know what im doing >.> im just finding it difficult to explain as ive never come across this problem using these functions before :) thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to convert a value from a string containing e.g. `"DEADBEEF"` to the integer value `0xDEADBEEF`? You are looking for the `strtol` family of functions.

```
void *ptr = (void *)strtoull("DEADBEEF", NULL, 16);
```

You can then do:

```
ReadProcessMemory(handle, ptr, &ValueOfAddress, sizeof(ValueOfAddress), 0);
printf("Value Of Address %p Is %d", ptr, ValueOfAddress);
```

Note that there is no error checking in that code (in particular, you should check that the value fits into a pointer and the string is valid hex).

Comment: Thank you this helped me go towards solving it big time :)!

Answer (score 0):

The data in the variable `MemoryAddress` is a pointer and not a string of characters. It needs to be converted into a string of characters before it can be combined it with other characters. C doesn't do this conversion automatically.

The `printf()` function is capable of accepting pointers (and integers and other types of numbers) and converting them to characters before printing them. That's what the format specifiers do (e.g. `%d` means "get the next parameter and convert it from signed int into characters, then insert the characters at this point").

In other words you can do this:

```
printf("Value At Address %p Is %d", (void *)MemoryAddress, ValueOfAddress);
```

The problem with this is that pointers in C are abstract and may not be a simple number (e.g. they might be two pieces, like "segment:offset"); and how pointers are displayed must be implementation defined so that code can be portable, and because it's implementation defined it may or may not use hexadecimal and may or many not use the `0x` prefix (depending on what the compiler felt like).

In other words; `%p` means "get the next parameter and convert it from a void pointer into characters using whatever makes sense for the specific type of CPU, then insert the characters at this point".

To force the pointer to be a single number and force `printf()` to display that single number in hexadecimal (without the `0x` suffix); if you're using C99 (or later) you can `#include <inttypes.h>` and do this:

```
printf("Value At Address " PRIXPTR " Is %d", (uintptr_t)MemoryAddress, ValueOfAddress);
```

Now we're back to the original problem - how to concatenate the `0x` suffix? C doesn't really support run-time concatenation internally (e.g. you'd need to use string related library functions - e.g. `strcat()`) and only supports compile-time string concatenation internally; and converting `MemoryAddress` into characters and then doing the concatenation with `strcat()` and then printing the concatenated string would be messy. The simplest solution is to avoid concatenation and put the `0x` into the format string instead, like this:

```
printf("Value At Address 0x" PRIXPTR " Is %d", (uintptr_t)MemoryAddress, ValueOfAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any concatenation.

`0x` in this context is just a prefix applied to a numeric constant to indicate that the given value is in hexadecimal format.  Whatever value gets assigned to `MemoryAddress` (which I'm assuming is a pointer type), is valid to pass as the second parameter to `ReadProcessMemory` by itself.